# HAProxy not working for port 80 for angular app running on 4200

Tags: angular, ubuntu, haproxy

I have an angular app running on 4200 port and I have added HAProxy to act as a reverse proxy.
To redirect all traffic on port 80 to 4200.
My HAProxy setting is working fine for 8080 to 4200 but not for 80 to 4200.

```
global
#       log /dev/log    local0
#       log /dev/log    local1 notice
#       chroot /var/lib/haproxy
#       stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
#       stats timeout 30s
#       user haproxy
#       group haproxy
        daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
    #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen http_frontend
    mode http
    option http-buffer-request
    bind *:80
    default_backend vapp

backend vapp
    mode http
    server ec2-15-200-79-226.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com ec2-15-200-79-226.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4200
```

Comment: Can you check the haproxy logs in `/var/log/haproxy.log`? Does it show anything suspicious?

Comment: Starting proxy http_frontend: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]
....seems not able to bind port 80

Answer (score 0):

Since in the logs it says about not being able to bind to port 80, there might be some problems:

- Are you running Nginx or something else on this port? Run `sudo netstat -ntlp` and check if another process is using this port. If so, you must stop them, or change your choice.
- Does haproxy have permission to bind to port 80? You must run it as root in order to be able to do so. Also you can check [this](https://serverfault.com/q/112795/523190) question about binding non-root processes to special ports.

Comment: You were right Nginx was running on 80, I stopped nginx and restarted as root.. I am getting now.."current worker exited with code 143"...any idea?

Comment: 143 is exit status of SIGTERM. It shows that you or the OS itself killed the process. Are you running haproxy as a systemd service? If so, what do `service haproxy status` and `journalctl -xe` say?